# How do you combine two functions in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

```
let rec test a b  = 
    match a with
    |[] -> []
    |(e,r)::tails -> if b = e then r::(test tails b)
                         else test tails b

let test2 g =
    match g with
    |e,r -> e, (test r)
```

I have 2 questions about the above two functions.

1. `test2` is calling `test`. How can I put `test` into `test2`, so it becomes one function?
2. In `test2`, on the line with `e,r ->e, (test r)` - `test` accept 2 arguments, but here we only pass `r`, so what does this line mean?

Answer (score 3):

Given question 2, I assume that you did not write these functions. So were did you get them, because they are very badly written (cf infra), so it's hard to know how to answer your questions... Anyway:

**1.** First, note that in many cases keeping two separate functions makes the code easier to read, maintain, reuse, etc... That said, there might be two ways to do it:

- you could either define `test` inside `test2`. In that case you would write (keeping your definitions of `test` and `test2` that is):

  ```
  let test2 g =
    let rec test a b  = 
      match a with
      |[] -> []
      |(e,r)::tails -> if b = e then r::(test tails b)
                       else test tails b
    in
    match g with
    |e,r -> e, (test r)
  ```
- Or, you could rewrite the function so that it performs all the operations, but usually that makes the code less clear -- in your case, I think it doesn't really make sense.

**2.** `test r` is just the partial application: it's a function which, when given one argument `b`, will return `test r b`. You should read this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying (although I'm not sure that the best introduction to the subject)

**3.** The function you gave are badly written, for several reasons. Here are some of them:

- `test` is not tailrec, when it could easily be (if you don't know what tailrec means, forget about it for now)
- the choice of the names is not very good -- so it's hard to know what is what.
- some expressions could be simplified. For instance, you could write:

  ```
  let test2 (e, r) = (e, test r)
  ```

Hope that helped you! =)